# string contains quotes character (')

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

i have a string for where clause, but the string contains quotes character (')

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM CsCustomer WHERE Name ='SA'MIR LUBIS'
```

and I get error from sql server. Any suggestions?

I use it to display the result into table cell

```
c = new TableCell();
c.Text = Db.SingleString("SELECT Unit FROM cscustomer WHERE Name='"+ r.Name +"'");
tr.Cells.Add(c);
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use Parameterized query. You can **escape the single quote** in the query `'` (another single quote)

Since the question has been tagged with C#, If you are building your query using Concatenation then you are bound to get such errors. Its better if you **use** [**SqlParameter**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)
Something like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM CsCustomer WHERE Name =@pName");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pName", "SA'MIR LUBIS"); //or any GUI control
```

This will also save you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: i want to show the result into table cell/textbox. how I can do this?

Comment: @FirmaAgnes Go and find out, the idea of SO is to help with a specific problem not complete your whole task

Comment: @FirmaAgnes, that is a separate question. It also depends on what kind of application you are targeting, but generally you can use a `DataGrid` and bound the data from DB. You need to search about it and come back to SO if you are stuck somewhere, May be this could be a good starting point http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=111

Comment: @Habib, Im sorry I think myquestion ist complete, please check my edited question. Thanks before

Comment: @FirmaAgnes, I am not sure about your method `Db.SingleString`'s implementation. You can instead use the simple ADO.Net parameterized query or for now you can try `r.Name.Replace("'","''")`, which would escape the single quote, later you can convert your code with SqlParameter

Answer (score 2):

You need to double them up or remove them if they aren't supposed to be there.

```
SELECT * FROM CsCustomer WHERE Name ='SA''MIR LUBIS'
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) class. Do like this:

```
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM CsCustomer WHERE Name = @name");
command.Parameters.Add("@name", "SA'MIR LUBIS");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quote mark ('') inside your text

SELECT * FROM CsCustomer WHERE Name ='SA''MIR LUBIS'

Comment: The OP doesn't want a quote - just double the `'` up instead of a quote.

Answer (score 1):

Use two quotes instead

```
SELECT * FROM CsCustomer WHERE Name ='SA''MIR LUBIS'
```

Also I will suggest to [Use Parameters Instead of String Concatenation](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Use_Parameters_Instead_of_String_Concatenation_for_Database_Queries_in_CSharp)

Answer (score 1):

you just simply need to escape the single quote, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CsCustomer WHERE Name ='SA''MIR LUBIS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like:

```
"SELECT * FROM CsCustomer WHERE Name =\'SA\'MIR LUBIS\'"
```

Or:

```
@"SELECT * FROM CsCustomer WHERE Name ='SA'MIR LUBIS'"
```